# Php Autocomplete with Oracle error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

I'm trying to use Auto-complete using Oracle.

I'd done this using MySQL, but with Oracle I got blank spaces.

This my MySQL Code.

```
      global $db;

     $term = trim(strip_tags(strtoupper($_GET['term'])));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

     $sql = "SELECT partNo as value FROM products WHERE partno LIKE '".$term."%' ORDER BY partNo LIMIT 15";
     Basic::EventLog('getPartNosFromDB-> '.$sql);
     $res =& $db->query($sql);

      while ($row=$res->fetchRow()){
                $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
                $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
      }
    echo json_encode($row_set);
```

And this is Oracle

```
      $term = trim(strip_tags(strtoupper($_GET['term'])));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

          $conn = oci_connect('XXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX');
                if (!$conn) {
                   $e = oci_error();
                   trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
                }
                 $sql = "SELECT product_definition as value FROM t_wip_job WHERE product_definition LIKE '".$term."%' AND ROWNUM < 16";
                 Basic::EventLog('getPartNosFromDB-> '.$sql);
                 $res = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
                 oci_execute($res);

                 while ($rowcc = oci_fetch_array($res, OCI_ASSOC)){
                    $row_set[] = $rowcc;//build an array
                 }
                echo json_encode($row_set);
```

If I execute these query the first returns -> [{"value":"A2C00000000"},{"value":"A2C00000001"}]  (MySQL)

And the second returns -> [{"VALUE":"A2C87115000"},{"VALUE":"A2C87114900"}] (Oracle)

But inside textbox when it tries to auto-complete the MySql result shows "A2C87115000" and "A2C87114900"

and the Oracle result shows " " and " ".

Comment: With Oracle, I believe that you have to double-quote the column name if you want it to be lower case (which you do, so that the resulting json keys are lower case).  So `$sql = "SELECT product_definition as \"value\" FROM…`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that... It was "kind of" easy... thank you man. It works like a charm !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with the case of the hash keys, since the MySql hash keys are lowercase (`"value"`), while the Oracle ones are uppercase (`"VALUE"`).
When you load the json, since javascript is case sensitive, looking for `"value"` it finds the content only in the first case.

Try having lowercase keys in both case. This should do the trick!